# is there a way to pause gnome from other tty?

Tags: gnome, tty

To run a virtual machine on my computer and to have more resources for it, I'd like to pause gnome. The idea is to go on other tty pause gnome from it and run my virtual machine with lower ram for the host than necessary with the use of gnome.
I did not found anything, I supposed it is not possible. But I'd like to be sure. That's why I ask the question here

My OS is linux mint 13.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way currently to freeze a process to disk on Linux and remove it from RAM, and even if there was, what you call GNOME is made up of many processes and programs that are all running at the same time so trying to co-ordinate what processes you needed to freeze would be tricky

Comment: I expected this answer and now I am sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more resources for your VM, you could sign out of Gnome and use another Desktop Environment while you use the virtual machine. If you used [window maker](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/wmaker) you would save hundreds of megabytes of ram. Window Maker only uses a few megabytes, and takes very little disk space.

---

If you do use Window Maker, then it is a little confusing at first. To access your applications, right click on the desktop, to get a menu. There is an application dock on the side of the screen, but by default it only holds an xterm launcher.

If your application is not in the applications menu, then you will need to start it using xterm. When is icon appears, drag it to the dock, and you will be able to launch it from there. To edit the application menu you need to right click on the desktop and select `Configure Window Maker`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I'd like to know if it is possible to pause gnome. The possibility to use an other X windows is not an option now. I spent hours to configure this linux mint, install and configure specific programs.